# EditText single line issue on Galaxy Tab

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, galaxy-tab

I have an Edit/text in my layout as:

```
<EditText
                    android:id="@+id/url"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="25dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" 
                    android:background="@drawable/url_edit_text_bg"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:inputType="textUri"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
```

But on my Galaxy tab 10.1 device I am unable to see long text on a single line in this EditText.

[image]

This issue is observed only on  **Galaxy tab 10.1 and Ideapad Tab K1**, on other devices such as Samsung galaxy note, Galaxy nexus, Nexus S, HTC Desire, Galaxy Y etc. the long url text fits on one single line.
Y are a few devices giving this issue?
How can it be solved?
Please help...
Thank you.

Comment: Give layout height as wrap_content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a standard behavior. You can try doing that in any browser.

Answer (score 0):

why are you giving constant height to EditText?

do the following changes:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: The drawable i'm using as the EditText background is a 9 patch.  And I have a button next to the EditText, I need to match EditText's height with that of the button, so I have specified a specific height for it.